# How to improve my oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query in Oracle which takes 3 or more seconds for a single request but, in my case, I execute it multiple times to process multiple records, so overall it takes more time.
To improve query performance I have done the following action.

I have executed SQL tuning Advisory and created suggested index, but suggested index does not work in execution plan, it shows the same previous primary key index, what I will do for it.

My query is:

```
Select NVL(Min(MACIDREFNO),0)
from   TACID_MST
Where  MacIdStatus = 2
And    Status = 0 
And    UsedAs = 1
And    IsCodeSigned = 0
And    SiteRefNo = 0;
```

And the Execution Plan is:
[Execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gADxc.jpg)

And result of SQL tuning Advisory is:

```
GENERAL INFORMATION SECTION `Result of Tuning Advisory`
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tuning Task Name                  : staName75534
Tuning Task Owner                 : TESTUSER
Tuning Task ID                    : 385915
Scope                             : COMPREHENSIVE
Time Limit(seconds)               : 1800
Completion Status                 : COMPLETED
Started at                        : 01/24/2018 15:46:15
Completed at                      : 01/24/2018 15:46:17
Number of Index Findings          : 1

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FINDINGS SECTION (1 finding)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1- Index Finding (`see explain plans section below`)
--------------------------------------------------
  The execution plan of this statement can be improved by creating one or more
  indices.

  Recommendation (estimated benefit: 100%)
  ----------------------------------------
  - Consider running the Access Advisor to improve the physical schema design
    or creating the recommended index.

        create index TESTUSER.IDX$$_5E37B0001 on
        TESTUSER.TACID_MST('STATUS','USEDAS','MACIDSTATUS','SITEREFNO','ISCODESIGNED');

  Rationale
  ---------
    Creating the recommended indices significantly improves the execution plan
    of this statement. However, it might be preferable to run "Access Advisor"
    using a representative SQL workload as opposed to a single statement. This
    will allow to get comprehensive index recommendations which takes into
    account index maintenance overhead and additional space consumption.
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the index the tuning advisory suggests?

Comment: What happened when you followed the recommendation?

Comment: Yes i have created index as suggest by tuning advisory but explain plan show only previously primary key used index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest ways:

- rebuild index sys_iot_top_147733 (if not IOT) or if possible move(rebuild) IOT
- use binding variables
- gather statistics on table TACID_MST
- change column order in new index (put the most restrictive column value first (the column with the highest unique values))
- use hint for force index use: select /*+ INDEX( TACID_MST your_index_name )*/ NVL(Min(MACIDREFNO),0) from

Comment: i have try with **rebuild index sys_iot_top_147733**, but getting error primary key index not rebuild. how can use binding variables.force index not working show previous primary key index on explain plan.

Comment: 1) as I understand, you use IOT (Index-Organized Tables) and you can rebuild IOT. 2) binding variables depends on the programming language, for example in Java use: PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("Select NVL(Min(MACIDREFNO),0)
from   TACID_MST
Where  MacIdStatus = ?
And    Status = ?
And    UsedAs = ?
And    IsCodeSigned = ?
And    SiteRefNo = ?");
   pstmt.setLong(1, 2);pstmt.setLong(1, 0);pstmt.setLong(1, 1);pstmt.setLong(1, 0);pstmt.setLong(1, 0);

Comment: you see new valid index in [select INDEX_NAME, STATUS from user_indexes where TABLE_OWNER = 'TESTUSER' and TABLE_NAME = 'TACID_MST']?

Comment: Thanks for help.Output of above query is ...`IDX$$_5E35E0001 VALID  (Suggested by query plan)
SYS_IOT_TOP_147733 VALID (Primary key index)
IXTACID_MST01 VALID
IXTACID_MST02 VALID` **Can you explain is primary key index is enough for this query**, if yes then why query optimizer show me missing index if no then how can apply proper index on this query.

Comment: **Row lock used on store with in store procedure** and commit code using delphi code, i have change this procedure and commit code with in store procedure after all update, insert and delete.Is this is right way to commit code with in store procedure or having any drawback.

Comment: commit for transaction and is determined by the program logic for data consistency. and i think use commit in procedure not good, because somebody can use you proc and commit transaction in middle.

Comment: primary key index maybe enough for this query. depends on the composition of the data. you can play with hints (not for production) for example use **/*+ RULE*/** for change to RULE optimizer from CHOOSE or conversely.

Comment: hint not working (force indexing) not working, i don't know why happen this.

Comment: Or can you tell me which partition is best for only two tables having 700 million rows.

Comment: the number of rows is not the deciding factor for partitioning and it does not guarantee speeding up the execution of queries. I can imagine that having only the id and status fields in table you can try to use hash partitioning.

Comment: Why recommended index not working in that case and explain say when i create an index it improve performance but why it not working in my case.

Comment: I have index organised on this table may be that's why index not working can i rebuild index on this table?

Comment: you can rebuild secondary index. i create simple IOT table and secondary index. by default optimizer use primary index but when i use hint INDEX optimizer used second index.  select /*+ INDEX(table_name index_name)*/ * from table_name. if use use alias for table you must change table_name by alias. strange why your hint do not work. and again this hint help to view different cases, but not for production.

Comment: Index hint working if you create a fresh copy of IOT but i have old IOT table.So can i rebuild primary index on it. because when i rebuild secondary index not found any  improvement. No hint working and also no_index hint also not working.