# Recommended index not working in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have single table select query having row count 700 million and i have select a primary key column and it takes 5 to 6 seconds.For optimize it i have create index as per suggest by below execution plan.
But only primary key index work it neglect reaming index.

Check this link 
[How to improve my oracle query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422025/how-to-improve-my-oracle-query)

Why **recommended index** not working in that case and explain say when i create an index it improve performance but why it not working in my case?
[Get SQL Tuning Advisory File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=34618561064471411083)

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve] to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle things that the index won't improve the query, Oracle might chose to ignore the index. In that case you can try forcing the index. Here's an example:

```
select /*+ INDEX(table_name index_name) */ from table
```

Comment: force index not working. i have also tried it but getting same execution plan.

Comment: I have also try same situation with another test database where i don't create primary key on selecting column and where create this type index.It working fine,so can i drop primary key on that table or suggest me what i can do in that case.

Comment: I have index organised table, can i rebuild index on it?